# -webkit-linear-gradient jquery and var

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to JQuery, so I most likely am doing this wrong.  When I try to do:

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  spectrum();

  function spectrum() {
    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.foor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';

    $('body').animate({
      background: '-webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, ' + hue + ' 0%, ' + hue + ' 100%)'
    }, 2500, spectrum);
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">  
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Moody Colors</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
  </head>

  <body></body>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-color/master/jquery.color.js"></script>
  <script src="js/moody.js"></script>
</html>
```

I just get a blank white page and no errors in the Chrome console.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying for solid background colors or gradients?

Comment: If you're using the latest version of jQuery (1.8), it does automatic CSS prefixing, so you don't need to speficy `-webkit-` in your jQuery code. You still need it in the CSS code, but you should also always specify the non-prefixed version as well, plus any prefixed versions for other browsers. Failure to do this will make your site break for some users.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already using CSS3, why not use [CSS3 transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) to change the background color?

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    spectrum();

    function spectrum() {
        var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';           
        $('body').css('background-color', '-webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, ' + hue + ' 0%, ' + hue + ' 100%)');
        setTimeout(spectrum, 2500);
    }
});​
```

CSS:

```
body {
    transition: background-color 2.5s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 2.5s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2.5s;
}
```

And the same HTML you are using now. [Demo here at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znB8c/)

(Added vendor prefixes for Firefox and WebKit, you will need to do that with the CSS added through JavaScript as well)

Comment: Thank you.  I will give that a try and report back. :)  Again, thank you!

Comment: What you gave worked, but the transition with the "webkit-linear-gradient" is very jerky and not smooth at all.  Take a look, [Example](https://s3.amazonaws.com/js-test-colors/).   Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting a Access Denied xml page when visiting the example.

Comment: Sorry,   fixed.           http://js-test-colors.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/